# .htaccess mod_rewrite - make rule ignore a file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I create this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ gallery.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But it's still affecting index.php file. So I tryed add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

With no result.

Is possible to tell mod_rewritte to ignore a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a negative lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/?$ gallery.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Or use a negative `RewriteCond` to get same effect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ gallery.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Or just avoid all files/directories from this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ gallery.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Work like a charm.